# Should I convert my MySQL database to JSON file?

Tags: mysql, json

I created a quiz website, the questions and answers are fixed, the data usually does't change.
When a user loads a quiz page, a query is made to the MySQL database to retrieve the question data (including answer, related image data etc). There are about 2000 questions total in the database. The query to the database is made based on the question's unique ID.

I would like to speed up the page loading time. I've read about making a query to the MySQL database and then converting the data into JSON format, but that seems like it would make the process longer. Should I convert the MySQL database into a single JSON file, then have the website's quiz page directly query the JSON file rather than the MySQL database to grab the question data?

Comment: Probably not. One good resource you should check out is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

Comment: Probably not. It is fine to ask MySQL and generate the JSON to send right then

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for JSON here unless you want to make AJAX requests 
 
This is a common scenario for webapps. The following may be a one of many approaches (assuming MySQL and PHP):
1. Load the single question page with $questionID in the URL (and read it with $_GET['questionID']) or you pass it as $_POST
2. Query the database with:
SELECT * 
FROM `questions` 
WHERE question_id = "(int)$questionID" 
LIMIT 1
3. Build your HTML with the info returned by your query 
4. Display your info to the user 
5. On $_POST check for right/wrong answers against answers table querying by $questionID and $answerID (you might need to loop thru them) 
6. Store the results in $_SESSION so you can show final results on the last page. 
 

Hope that helps,

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing, but would a JSON file provide the data faster to the page than MySQL?